# Add iframe with jQuery from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Hi I have page which is under `HTTPS`, because I can manipulate only `JS` and `CSS` on it, I created free host `HTTP` and upload content there. After that I added with `jQuery`, `iframe` element to the `HTTPS` page with `src` to the `HTTP` page, but I see this error in the console:

`Mixed Content: The page at 'https://url.bg/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://url.000webhostapp.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

This is for Chrome and this for Mozilla:
`Blocked loading mixed active content “http://url.000webhostapp.com/”`

Is there any solution for that ?

My `JS` code is simple:

```
$('body').children().remove();
$('body').append('<iframe src="http://inovativa.000webhostapp.com/"></iframe>');
```

Comment: is url.000 == innovativa.00 ? or a redirect?

Comment: Your browser setting doesn't allow insecure content to be served on the secure page. Meaning your original page is loaded over HTTPS and if you try to load any content from HTTP source like CSS, JS or in your case Iframe, then it will be blocked. Only way to avoid this is to host the Iframe content over HTTPS.

Comment: @karthick answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don you write url agnostic code?

https page needs to load https resources. If the external link has support for https then load the url using '//', which means when you page is in http load the resource using http protocol. if in https then https.

```
$('body').append('<iframe src="//inovativa.000webhostapp.com/"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Probably because 000Webhost doesn't support HTTPS. (They're a free web host, and a lot of standard web hosting features are unavailable or broken on their service.)

Comment: I thought the same initially then i refered the link https://inovativa.000webhostapp.com/. It has the support for it.